# Problem in installing CUDA on Intel-Nvidia hybrid graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA 7.5 on my dell laptop which has both Intel and Nvidia GeForce 820M cards. Initially I installed it from .run file and went through so many problems like blackscreen on boot up, etc. After solving those, when I ran deviceQuery, I got error : No CUDA capable device detected.
The error is right as I cant find /dev/nvidia* anywhere.

Here is my `inxi -bG` output:

```
System: Host: shubh-Inspiron-3542 
Kernel: 3.13.0-93-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
Desktop: Gnome 3.10.4 
Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine: System: Dell (portable) product: Inspiron 3542
Mobo: Dell model: 0926J6 version: A03 
Bios: Dell version: A03 date: 05/27/2014
CPU: Dual core Intel Core i5-4210U CPU (-HT-MCP-) clocked at 782.00 MHz
Graphics: Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz
GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
Network: Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k
Card-2: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller driver: r8169
Card-3: Atheros
Drives: HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (6.0% used)
Info: Processes: 207 Uptime: 5 min Memory: 1077.5/3857.5MB Client: Shell
```

I cant find NVIDIA card here;

But when I ran `lspci | grep -i nvidia`, I got:

```
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

Also for running `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`, I got output:

```
rc bumblebee-nvidia 3.2.1-9~gpu14.04.1 amd64 NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
rc nvidia-304 304.131-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 amd64 NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.131
ii nvidia-340 340.96-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 amd64 NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96
ii nvidia-common 1:0.2.91.11 amd64 transitional package for ubuntu-drivers-common
rc nvidia-opencl-icd-304 304.131-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 amd64 NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii nvidia-opencl-icd-340 340.96-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 amd64 NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii nvidia-prime 0.6.2 amd64 Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii nvidia-settings 331.20-0ubuntu8 amd64 Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Currently I have restored my system by installing old nvidia driver 340, and have CUDA 6.5 installed as I was experimenting it with nvidia 340 driver. However,I want CUDA 7.5 to be installed in my machine if possible.
I am fed up from re-installing nvidia driver for getting black screen upon boot up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to upgrade, I successfully deployed CUDA on an unencumbered NVIDIA GPU in 16.04 .. these steps may even work in 14.x as long as you mimic the instructions regarding the `.run` files

[Severe under performance of CUDA vs Windows, make intel primary GPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952426/severe-under-performance-of-cuda-vs-windows-make-intel-primary-gpu/953051#953051)